# "Sorry, unable to map your existing skeleton" in Mixamo on a model after Blender export as FBX

Tags: animation, .fbx, mixamo

I have this FBX model:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/rigged-t-pose-human-male-w-50-face-blendshapes-cc7e4596bcd145208a6992c757854c07

When I upload this into Mixamo, it works out of the box.

But when I import the fbx into Blender and (do some changes, or even not) and export it as FBX and try to upload on Mixamo, I get that error.

Maybe I am doing something wrong on the export from Blender - since it is the same model and structure and polygons it should work.

[image]

I saw this error is not new, but I checked some aspects, like not using metal in shaders..

what could it be? can someone try it "quickly" (I really appreciate it! <3)

Comment: By default Blender adds ""leaf-bones" to the armature which are extra bones after exporting. Did you disabled it? It can be found in the "Armature" menu of the exporter window (bottom of the picture).

Comment: @FFeller Leaf-bones are disabled.. (or enabled); it doesn't matter, after export from blender Mixamo gives me this error. Could you give it a quick try? (without blender, it works, import fbx in blender and export it: doesn't work anymore)

Comment: I tried the file, same happens to me. But if you don't modify the aramture, you can download the animation with the original fbx and import the animations to Blender and use them on the modified model.